# CSS3 Rotate Animation

Tags: image, css, animation, rotation

```
<img class="image" src="" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

Cannot get this animated image to work, it is supposed to do a 360 degrees rotation.

I guess something's wrong with the CSS below, as it just stays still.

```
.image {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-left: -60px;

    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;

    @-ms-keyframes spin { 
        from { 
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); 
        } to { 
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes spin { 
        from { 
            -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); 
        } to { 
            -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin { 
        from { 
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
        } to { 
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
        }
    }
    @keyframes spin { 
        from { 
            transform: rotate(0deg); 
        } to { 
            transform: rotate(360deg); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 709, accepted):

Here is a **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Ugc5g/)**. The correct animation CSS:

```css
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
@keyframes spin { 
    100% { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
        transform:rotate(360deg); 
    } 
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC1Tv.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

---

Some notes on your code:

1. You've nested the keyframes inside the `.image` rule, and that's incorrect
2. `float:left` won't work on absolutely positioned elements
3. Have a look at [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation): IE10 doesn't need the `-ms-` prefix

Comment: If anyone tries this in their own code: DONT FORGET THE @ section at the bottom

Comment: Hello Can I stop animation Infinity rotation after 5s ?

Comment: I almost spat my water out when I ran the animation.

Comment: " `float:left won't work on absolutely positioned elements` " , it will shrink them to minimum size though, similar to what display: inline-block does

Comment: 1 second rotates, 5 times ( `animation:spin 1s linear 5;` ) or 5 seconds rotate, 1 time ( `animation:spin 5s linear 1;` ) and then stop.

Comment: None of the prefixes on `animation` and `transform` is needed anymore in 2023. I would suggest editing those out of the answer (in 2013 of course, they **were** necessary).

Answer (score 70):

To achieve the 360 degree rotation,  here is the [Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/sELBM/426/).

**The HTML:**

```
<img class="image" src="your-image.png">
```

**The CSS:**

```
.image {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-property: transform;
}
.image:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

You have to hover on the image and you will get the 360 degree rotation effect.

PS: Add a `-webkit-` extension for it to work on chrome and other webkit browers. You can check the updated fiddle for webkit **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sELBM/426/)**

Comment: Fiddle doesn't work o.O Chrome inspector does not like your CSS, specifically the "transform" and "transition-property". Oh dear.

Comment: For that you need to add a `-webkit-tranform` for it to work. Here is the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sELBM/172/ - @JustPlainHigh

Comment: 2017: This is now very well supported and a preferred way to do non-infinite rotations. `-webkit-` prefix is no longer needed and can be safely removed. Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms

Comment: Clean and beautiful

Answer (score 36):

I have a rotating image using the same thing as you:

```
.knoop1 img{
    position:absolute;
    width:114px;
    height:114px;
    top:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left:-195px;
    z-index:0;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
     transition-property: transform;

     overflow:hidden;
}

.knoop1:hover img{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: add: `transform:rotate(360deg);` for IE

Comment: Please choose local examples over broken website links.

Comment: Link is broken now.

Answer (score 4):

try this easy

```css
 
 .btn-circle span {
     top: 0;
   
      position: absolute;
     font-size: 18px;
       text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
      -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}

.btn-circle span :hover {
 color :silver;
}


/* rotate 360 key for refresh btn */
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle" ><span class="glyphicon">&#x21bb;</span></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to flip image you can use it.

```
.image{
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation:spin 3s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 3s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 3s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 50% { -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 50% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 50% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg); transform:rotateY(90deg); } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The another method to rotate an object in the background using css3, check out the below css3 code here:

```
.floating-ball-model-3 > span {
    animation-name: floating-ball-model-3;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-name: floating-ball-model-3;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 7s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: floating-ball-model-3;
    -moz-animation-duration: 7s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: floating-ball-model-3;
    -ms-animation-duration: 7s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-name: floating-ball-model-3;
    -o-animation-duration: 7s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
}


@keyframes floating-ball-model-3 {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to { 
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: The non-prefixed properties should generally come last. The reasoning is that properties overwrite each other, so if the browser supports the non-prefixed versions, these should overwrite any non-standard values set above.

Answer (score -10):

Here this should help you

The below jsfiddle link will help you understand how to rotate a image.I used the same one to rotate the dial of a clock.

http://jsfiddle.net/xw89p/

```
var rotation = function (){
   $("#image").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation,
      easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){       
          return c*(t/d)+b;
      }
   });
}
rotation();
```

Where:
•   t: current time,

•   b: begInnIng value,

•   c: change In value,

•   d: duration,

•   x: unused

No easing (linear easing):
   function(x, t, b, c, d) { return b+(t/d)*c ; }

Comment: I would upvote this answer if you provide a bit more information (like you do in the fiddle). I also feel you should mention this is a jQuery plugin because I was all like, "I didn't know jQuery could do that!!! ^_^ *looks at fiddle* Oh wait... U_U"

Comment: an explanation of the x,t,b,c,d variables (like you do in the fiddle) and clearly stating that although it isn't a CSS solution as requested by OP, it is quite a simple and effective jQuery plugin solution :)

Comment: Downvoted. The OP didn't request a Javascript solution, especially not a jQuery plugin. Stick to what's being asked.