# jQuery .rotate() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, css-transforms

I don't know why it don't work. I am using jQuery 2.1.0

I have this code:

`$("a.shownav img").rotate(180);`

How can I make it work **without** using a plugin?

Comment: there is no rotate() method in jquery, but might be you were seeing from a plugin....

Comment: see the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020904/how-to-rotate-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: Add some relevant HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for using `.rotate()`, you need to add [jqueryrotate](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/]) plugin. This can be also achieved using pure jQuery and CSS.

Try this:

```
$("a.shownav img").css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(180deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotate(180deg)",
    "transform": "rotate(180deg)" /* For modern browsers(CSS3)  */
});
```

Comment: @C-link: do you know what is `.rotate()` is. and isnt `$("a.shownav img").css({` jquery

Comment: Without using a plugin, how do I animate this rotation? `.animate()` won't work for me.

Comment: @GigaByte568: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771225/css3-rotate-animation

Answer (score 3):

Use .css() in jquery

```
$("a.shownav img").css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
```

Comment: there is no rotate method in jquery using css only we can acheive this