# Rotate() is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, rotation

In my project I created a canvas in which:

- An image is loaded into the canvas
- Possibility of resizing the uploaded image

Now I'm trying to add the rotate function to rotate the loaded image inside the canvas when I hold down the mouse.

I tried to add the rotate () function but the error message it returns is: **$(...).rotate is not a function**

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" class="resize" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></canvas>
<input type="file" id="file-input">
```

JS

```
$(function() {
            
            $('#file-input').change(function(e) {
                var file = e.target.files[0],
                    imageType = /image.*/;

                if (!file.type.match(imageType))
                    return;

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = fileOnload;
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            });

            function fileOnload(e) {
                var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
                $img.load(function() {
                    var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
                    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
                    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                });
            }
            
            $(document).mouseup(function(e) 
            {
                var container = $(".ui-wrapper");

                // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
                if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
                {
                    $("#canvas").css("border-style","hidden");
                    $(".ui-resizable-handle").attr("style","visibility: hidden");
                } else {
                        $("#canvas").css("border-style","solid");
                        $(".ui-resizable-handle").attr("style","visibility: visible");
                }
            });
            
            
                window.zindex = 30;

                $(".resize").resizable({handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'});
                $(".resize").parent().draggable({
                    stack: "div"
                });
                
                
        //SCRIPT PER ROTAZIONE LOGO
        $(".resize").rotate({
                    bind: {
                        dblclick: function() {
                            $(this).data('angle', $(this).data('angle')+90);
                            var w = $(this).css('width');
                            $(this).parent().rotate({ animateTo: $(this).data('angle')}).css({width: $(this).css('height'), height: w});

                        }
                    }
                });
            
                
                
        
        
        });
```

This instead is the example of how I would like the effect to come:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/QqwKR/

In this example, however, the image is immediately loaded into the canvas. Instead, I want the rotate effect to appear when I uploaded the photo into the canvas with the input file.

Comment: *I tried to add the rotate() function* - what "rotate" function?  Where did you see this?  What makes you think it exists?  Where's its documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery .rotate() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338620/jquery-rotate-doesnt-work)

Comment: You probably just meant to include the [jqueryroate plugin](https://jqueryrotate.com/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't appear to have any "handles" to rotate with

Comment: @freedomn-m exactly my fiddle have not any "handles" because rotate function is not defined. I tried to include jQueryrotate plugin in my fiddle but not work again...

Comment: Then it's not "an example of how it should work".  Looks like it's not working because the image is 404.  **edit** yes, that was it - "works" (badly) with an actual image - http://jsfiddle.net/j2uLv37e/  that fiddle is using [canvas rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate) - what exactly do you want to rotate?  a canvas or a div?

Comment: In my example that I have put, only the address of the image on which the rotation effect is applied is missing. The rest all works. Please try changing the image link to "img.src" and you will see that everything will work

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This post is duplicated. Anyways, there is no method like `rotate()` in jQuery. You need to use **[`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method to apply `transform`.

```js
$(this).css('transform','rotate(45deg)');
```

Comment: Man i tried to use $("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {         $(this).css('transform','rotate(45deg)');}); but not work well because I want to freely rotate the logo with the mouse as in the example