# Rotation button on hover

Tags: javascript, css, rotation

So I'm looking to make an image rotate button appear on hover. I thought I had the idea down with some CSS, but I must have done it incorrectly. See my fiddle here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdcutter/6sw9yrmk/4/)

Thanks in advance

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#foo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px; 
    border-spacing: 0;
    background:none;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

button {display:none;}

#foo img {width:100%;}
  #foo img:hover button {display: block;}
```

**JS**

```
function rotateFoo(){
    var angle = ($('#foo').data('angle') + 1080) || 1080;
    $('#foo').css({'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
    $('#foo').data('angle', angle);
}
```

Comment: the answer here should help, just remove the infinite attribute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771225/css3-rotate-animation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following rules

```
#foo:hover + button, button:hover {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sw9yrmk/7/).

You can adjust the left and top position suitable to your needs, but you should note that the button must be on top of the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.hover()` if you need js logic -> https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: This would also do. Thanks for your answer @dodo121

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using JQuery, would this solution work for yo https://jsfiddle.net/6sw9yrmk/13/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseenter', '.divbutton', function() {
    $(this).find(":button").show();
  }).on('mouseleave', '.divbutton', function() {
    $(this).find(":button").hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: This option would work too, minus the button rolling with it. Still giving you a 1up