# Rotate my logo on website

Tags: wordpress, css, css-animations

I have a WordPress site: http://powersmart.tech/wordpress/

I want my webiste logo to rotate like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2h29c8zdpfmuvi/video-1477647190.mp4?dl=0

I have made my logo to rotate in a circle using following code:

```
#Top_bar #logo img {
 -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
 animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: That's not a rotate animation, but rather a scaleX.

Comment: please check this link:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771225/css3-rotate-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong transformation type, this is achieved using `scaleX` rather then `rotate`. I've made a small demo how this should work:

```css
#logo {
    margin: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    50% {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(0.1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.1);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.1));
        transform: scaleX(0.1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"> hi </div>
```