# Yin Yang like css with empty center

Tags: css

I have this loader here: https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/hdn3wqmd/2/

I'm trying to make it look like this

[image]

I'm not sure this can be done with borders alone, i've tried a bunch of variations of border width/radius etc, but it never comes out right.

```
.loader {
    border-top: 40px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-bottom: 40px solid darkblue; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

EDIT: I'm not asking about making it spin. I'm asking how to create my provided image above with css. You'll notice that a Yin Yang's shape fills a circle. My desired shape does not, and has an empty center.

Comment: This help? https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/EGQab/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 Rotate Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771225/css3-rotate-animation)

Comment: @Michael, not exactly. I'm not looking for a yin yang, my example has an empty center. Nick, that's not what my question is.

Answer (score 0):

Is it Okay..

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;

}
div{
  
display:inline-block;
}
.loader {
    border-top: 40px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-bottom: 40px solid darkblue; /* Blue */
     border-radius:75% 25% 75%;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     transform: rotate(35deg);
     margin-left:25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Or You can try some more adjustments here