# How do I make an image rotate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/uUYXqAv.png">

img {  
  width: 100%;
}
```

I want to make the earth spinning.

https://jsfiddle.net/La3qbr0v/

Comment: i Think that this subject is been answered in here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771225/css3-rotate-animation)

Comment: i think this subject is been answered in This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771225/css3-rotate-animation)

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use keyframes:

```
img {
    position: absolute;   
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

See here:

https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/47z5bro3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS transforms.

```
img {
  transform:rotate(ydeg);
}
```

( y being any number between 0 and 360 )

If you want to animate it you can use keyframes - https://codepen.io/quangogage/pen/OjYvNG?editors=1111

Answer (score 2):

Below is my code. My [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j00goq5c/).

```css
img {    
width: 100%;
animation: rotate 60s ease infinite;
-webkit-animation: rotate 60s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate{
  100%{ transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate{
  100%{ transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/uUYXqAv.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script that sets a variable and then have a function set an interval to rotate your picture.

```
var start = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
     setInterval(function() {
          $("picture").rotate(start);
     }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Although this would work, its not as efficient  as using CSS. JQuery is slow and should be avoided when the same functionality can be done using CSS

Comment: You dont need JS.  CSS Is enough