# How do I make a looping rotating image?

Tags: html

So I wonder how to rotate a image in HTML, normal speed and using a simple trick.
Somebody could help me?

```css
\*Dont know how to do it*\
```

```html
<img src="https://google.com/favicon.ico"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rotate a img using [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) css property

You can try this

```css
img {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  animation: rotate 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
    <img src="https://google.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: If you add `linear` to the `animation` setting, it will rotate continuously without stopping in between...

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {
    position: absolute;   
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico">
```

No worries, found it out!
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46085346/17699715

Answer (score 1):

im not sure if this what you ask for !

```css
.rotate {
  animation: rotation 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="rotate"  width="100" height="100" src="https://google.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Almost, yeah! But it counts. TYSM!