# CSS animation: adjust background color flashing speed given the BPM and beats

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a "simple" CSS animation that works as a metronome:

i would like to have a DIV with

- the background color "smoothly flashing" given the BPM and the number of Beats
- the first beat should flash with a different color
- If possible, a beat counter (the DIV text content)

Why only CSS? 'cause i'd like to learn how far i can go with it, and 'cause it will keep the final page "simple" (no javascript files or code in it other than the two variables "BPM" and "BEATS".

I tried by following online examples and tutorial, or answers here on stackoverflow, but got stuck pretty soon:

```
.metronome {
  color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5rem;
    animation: tempo 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
    0%   {background-color: var(--title-bgcolor);}
    50%  {background-color: var(--lyric_block-bgcolor);}
    100% {background-color: var(--title-bgcolor);}
}
@keyframes tempo {
    0%   {content:"1"; background-color: #8FF;}
    5%   {background-color: #8FF;}
    24%  {background-color: #000;}
    25%  {content:"2"; background-color: #08F;}
    49%  {background-color: #000;}
    50%  {content:"3"; background-color: #08F;}
    74%  {background-color: #000;}
    75%  {content:"4"; background-color: #08F;}
    99%  {background-color: #000;}
    100% {background-color: #8FF;}
}
```

([here](https://codepen.io/parduz/pen/rNoogre)'s the codepen i tryed to make)

i don't see how to manipulate the animation time and number keyframes according to the given BPM and BEATS. But i strongly suspect that my approach may be wrong.

Can it be done? How?

Comment: Let's start with - what does _"according to the given BPM and BEATS"_ actually mean? The B in BPM stands for Beats already, so why do you want to specify _"the number of Beats"_ separately here? I can't currently tell what exactly you want your animation to do, based on those _two_ values.

Comment: _"i don't see how to manipulate the animation time and number keyframes according to the given BPM and BEATS."_ - the `animation-duration` could be set via a CSS variable; but you can't make the _number_ of keyframes "dynamic." If you actually need the latter - then you will have to generate your CSS dynamically.

Comment: Alternatively, setup multiple css rules, eg `.metronome-50 {...` `.metronome-120 {..`

Comment: It's unclear how much "no javascript" is your limit (given that you state "no" javascript them immediately give an example of what javascript is allowed).

Comment: You *can* use a CSS variable and then change that variable via js without rebuilding your CSS - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402471/how-to-use-javascript-variables-in-css  (but I doubt you can apply that to keyframes)

Comment: @CBroe at a guess it would be "beats per bar", eg OP has likely used 4/4 time, but may want 2/4, 2/2, 2/6 or any number of beats, (typically, 2, 3, 4 or 6 - or any, 13 is not unheard of) beats per bar - ie which one is the first beat as OP mentions the first beat as a different colour.   Then BMP would be the tempo.

Comment: @CBroe: About BEATS: TL:DR; i need to "highlight" the 1st beat, and all the other (BEATS-1) beats are not highlighted.
Long explanation:
"BEATS" means "How much beats per measure", in order to highlight the first one. "Normal" music is labeled "4/4", so 4 beats per measure (as my current code actually do).
Some songs have 3, some weird one 7 , etc.

Comment: @freedomn-m: 
*"It's unclear how much "no javascript" is your limit"*

it is not clear even for me; i don't know what's feasible and what not.
"As less as we reasonably can" i'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only way with configurable css variables `--bpm` and `--beats`.

```css
.metronome {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.metronome::before, .metronome::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  right: 0; left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: blink var(--blink-duration) infinite;
}

.metronome::before {
  --bg-blink: #08F;
  --blink-duration: calc(60s / var(--bpm));
}

.metronome::after {
  --bg-blink: #0FF;
  --blink-duration: calc(60s / var(--bpm) * var(--beats));
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% { background-color: var(--bg-blink); }
  50% { background-color: transparent; }
}
```

```html
<div class="metronome" style="--bpm: 120; --beats: 4;">4/4, 120bpm</div>
```

I tried to keep it to a single `div` and single `blink` animation. The key insight is the only difference between the bpm blink and the beats blink is that they happen at different time intervals, but they are otherwise exactly the same.

If you want to display the current beat number in the div, that's when I'd invoke the Javascript card, as you will need to set `textContent`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. 
Playing with it allow me to understand what's happening, and i think it's very clever. The only little problem is that you can't make the first beat length exactly long as the other beats, but i'm really nitpicking.


Please, if you could show me how to write the beat number i'll see how to sync css animation and javascripts.