# 3D Image rotation CSS

Tags: javascript, css, image, animation, rotation

In the following post the image rotates in the plane of the screen [CSS3 Rotate Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771225/css3-rotate-animation), can you help me out on how to make an image rotate into the plane of the page using CSS/JS?

I have added a gif to show the type of rotation I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: what is the plane you mean here ?

Comment: @ridoansaleh I've updated my post so that it is clearer! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: There are basically 3 types of rotations in CSS X , Y , Z this one is a part of Y axis rotation..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May this help you -:

```
.coin{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: red;
        animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
        perspective: 800px;
    }
@keyframes animate {
    0%{
       transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
```

You need to add a div in html file -

```
<div class='coin'></div>
```

I hope this was what you were expecting.. Thanks

Comment: If you need any explanation or further help..You can ask.

Answer (score 2):

What you need simplifies to this:

```
.image{
    animation: spin 1.2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

First, select the image and set animation to an animation with arbitrary name (spin sounds good for something rotating, but choose what you want. `spin` is the name i choose, 1.2s is duration but it can be ms as well like `500ms` or `1200ms`.

Then, define the animation by calling `@keyframes animationName` and then every attributte may be a percentaje, or from/to keywords like this too:

```
@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

But by using that way you can't customize that much, you only get a starting and a finish point. With percentajes you can define the animation to do many different stuff.

I hope this helps you out, and let me know if need to clarify something.

Comment: thanks for the answer it is really helpful but it isn't the type of rotation I am looking for, I've updated my post so that it more clear.