# How to tilt an image into 3d with css?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to make an image look 3d with css. I apologize if I don't describe that properly, heres an image of what I'm looking for
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9V8T.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3D Image rotation CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62482024/3d-image-rotation-css)

Answer (score 1):

The CSS transform property lets you do this with a rotate3D value which sets the axis of rotation and the amount to be rotated. In this case the only axis you are interested in is the Y-axis.

Here is a really simplistic example. You need to read up about the various settings to get exactly what you want, especially to accommodate different screen sizes appropriately.

```css
img {
  width: 20vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 20vw;
  height: auto;
 transform: perspective(200px) rotate3D(0, 1, 0, 30deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 45deg);
```

Add this to your img in css. It rotates the img 45 degrees from the y-axis.

Comment: Please read [answer] and add a working [repro]  for validation. A `code-only` answer can be considered low-quality. They are hard to understand and as such hard or impossible to reproduce.