# How to make a loading Spinner with my logo

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Hi i need to make a Loading spinner with css, js or anyone from my Logo. I have the Logo as PNG, GIF, SVG all formats. I want use it for longer site loads, picture loads or anyone and integrate it in my Vue3 Project.

Have anyone Solutions or guides for that, iam on google at 4 hours and nothing shows me right that.

thanks

Comment: 4 hours on google and not a single article about your problem? LOL ok ill play dumb

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771225/css3-rotate-animation

Answer (score 0):

You can just use CSS and setup an animation to have the logo spin

[here](https://flaviocopes.com/rotate-image/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mylogo{
  animation: rotation 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.transparentpng.com/download/circle-png/5CC7Ci-circle-png-picture.png" class="mylogo" width="80px"  />
```